# MVC4 web api not finding default document once deployed to webserver

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis-7, asp.net-web-api

It works on localhost, but finds no default document on the webserver and complains about directory browsing being disabled. IIS7 on both, and both websites/app pools seem to be configured identically.

I've used the web api template in VS2012, which doesn't actually have any views. It only has an Index controller action in the HomeController.

Any ideas on why this could produce different behavior in the two environments?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, have you published an MVC app to this server before?

Comment: Yes, it has one other MVC site on it (on a different port) which works as expected.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So this addition to my web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
<system.webServer>
```

fixed the problem. It seems to be required in the web.config for IIS7 on Windows 2008 Server, but not for IIS7 on Windows 7.

Comment: Thanks! I got this issue when deploying web api manually or using a web package.

Answer (score 0):

I had a user trying to publish a MVC4 application on IIS7 getting this error, it turned out it was because the user had set the application pool to use .Net 2 instead of .Net 4. Instead of getting an error indicating this though they received the above error, and it was only when we added the above module the real issue was uncovered.